# iOS app lag after some time without interactions

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, opengl-es, video-streaming

I have an iOS app that streams a computer's screen to the device and displays that using OpenGLES. So far, the frame rate is really good. I always stay at 60 for the rendering, no problem there.

The main problem is that after 8-10 seconds, a weird lag appears. I made a video to describe it. An even weirder thing, when I interact with the UI (e.g. the iOS top bar), the lag goes away for an other 8-10 seconds, and then comes back.

[Here's the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgzimcynLyg).

Profiling the app, there's a clear increase in CPU usage when the lag is present. The drop you can see is when the app is running smoothly.

[image: Profiling]

For 10 seconds of lag, the main thread has about 1s of CPU time, and the background thread (for receiving frames and decoding) uses around 7.5 seconds.

For 10 seconds of smoothness, the main thread will use around 450ms of CPU time, and the background thread uses 3.5 seconds.

I feel like iOS is changing the priority of some threads when the devices isn't used (or appears not to be used). The background thread is not becoming heavier in any way, I could keep pulling the iOS top bar constantly and get a perfect video this way. I'm really not sure what could cause this kind of behaviour.

I looked into changing the thread priorities, but that didn't change anything. I also tried to disable OpenGL texture uploads and/or disable renders, not even better.

I used to use VNC to stream the video and I had the same problem, so I don't think it's related to the network/decoding of the video stream.

Comment: Sounds like power management at work. Do the performance analysis tools you have available allow you to trace CPU clock frequencies?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I don't think it's possible to track CPU frequency on iOS devices, but I'll look into that. The device seems to be using less power when the lag is present than when it's not (according to the Energy Log profiler tool). Weird.

Comment: use power saving and try this without cable. will it always lag or no?

Comment: That would confirm that it's power management. Device goes into a lower power state, runs slower, and uses less energy. I don't know iOS much. You might want to see if there are APIs to influence power management, e.g. by setting some form of priority for your app.

Comment: Just tried with power saving while unplugged. The jitter seems to go away but the performance drop is such that it's actually hard to tell if it's lagging or not. Pulling the iOS top bar thing doesn't appear to change the frame rate though, which makes me think you're right about the power management. I'll look into getting into another power state when my app is running.

Comment: I also just tried to subscribe to the `NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChangeNotification` event, but the power state doesn't change.